# Passing parameter to init() function becomes nil

Tags: swift, parameters, null, initialization

I faced a problem with initializing my class instance.

I pass value `len = Lengh.new(5)` - non-`nil` value (I checked it during debugging) - as a parameter to init() function:

```swift
let len1 = Length.new(value: 5)
let s = Segment(length: len1)
```

Initializer looks like this:

```swift
public class Segment {
    var name: String?
    var length: Length?

    public init(name: String? = nil, length: Length? = nil) {
        self.length = length
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

After running, I have `s.length = nil`. (why!?) And this problem occurs during debugging too when stepping into the init() value of parameter `length` is already `nil`.

I am interested in why does this happens.
Thank you.

UPD:

This is how my `Length.new()` method looks like:

```swift
extension Length {
    static func new(value: Double) -> Length {
        Length(value: value, unit: .meters)
    }
}
```

By the way, the Length is a typealias:

```swift
public typealias Length = Measurement<UnitLength>
```

Comment: If you use secong optional parametr - you must define first optional parametr, or create a new init(length: Length? = nil)
Try use let s = Segment(name: nil, length: len1)

Comment: Something else is going on that's not included in the code. If `Length.new` generates an instance of `Length` (which is non-nil, as you claim), then `s.length` in the code above would also be non-nil

Comment: @ВладимирКовальчук, `If you use secong optional parametr - you must define first optional parametr,` - that's not correct

Comment: We need to see what `Length.new()` does because your code will only set `s.length` to `nil` if `nil` is passed in.

Comment: @JeremyP, I have updated the question. Also while debugging I checked that the passing parameter is not equal to nil.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem. When I run your code in a playground, the value of `length` gets set to 5 metres as expected.